# Schrodinger Equation: Is this derivation allowed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In reading material given for a course, I saw the following two statements:

> $$H\psi_n = E_n \psi_n$$

Where all the $\psi_n$ are eigenfunctions of $H$.

The next step given is

> $$e^{\frac{iHt}{h}}\psi_n = e^{\frac{iE_nt}{h}}\psi_n.$$

Does the second statement follow naturally from the first one? Am I allowed to raise the operators to the power as shown? Or is there some derivation missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of prior research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is allowed. One can define $e^H = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H^n}{n!}$. Since H is diagonal, it can be replaced by its eigenvalues giving the identity.

Comment: Hey, I didn't quite understand the 'since H is diagonal, it can be replaced by eigenvalues' part.

Comment: When applying an operator to its eigenvectors, one obtains that same eigenvector multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue. That is the content of the first expression in your question. The eigenvectors are said to 'diagonalise' the operator, since that operator can be expressed as a diagonal matrix in the basis given by the eigenvectors. Since the operator, when applied to its eigenvectors, just gives some number $E_n$, it can (in that case) be replaced by its eigenvalues.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of eigenvalue?

Comment: @my2cts, yeah, but not very comfortable with it yet. Btw, this replacement is only possible for  the eigenvectors, right?

Comment: The expansion is always allowed as long as there is convergence, I presume, for every matrix element. It was just easier to explain it by using eigenfunctions.